# Calculating P(R | O, D) in a Bayes Network

Tags: probability

I am practicing some conditional probability questions for an exam, but I am stuck on the last part of a practice question that involved a Bayes Network. The question is as follows:

*Rising ocean levels (O) can be a result of global warming (G), or be a sign that Ragnarök (R) has started, the final apocalypse in Norse mythology. Another result of Ragnarök is that the sun is devoured (D) by the Fenris wolf. The probability that Ragnarök has started is 10%, but global warming is happening with 90% probability. If Ragnarök is happening, then it is absolutely certain that the oceans will rise and the sun will be devoured. However, if Ragnarök is not happening, we have the following probabilities:*

- $ P(D | ¬R) = 0.2 $
- $ P(O | ¬R, G) = 0.8 $
- $ P(O | ¬R, ¬G) = 0.4 $

I have drawn a Bayes Net for the given information:

[image: Bayes Net]

The four questions are:

1. What is the probability that the sun is devoured? $ P(D) = 0.28 $
2. What is the probability that Ragnarök is happening, given that the sun is devoured? $ P(R | D) = 0.357 $
3. What is the probability of Ragnarök, given that the oceans are rising? $P(R | O) = 0.128 $
4. What is the probability of Ragnarök, given that the oceans are rising and that the sun is devoured? $P(R | O, D)$ = ???

My attempt so far is:
$$ P(R | O, D) = \frac{P(R, O, D)}{P(O, D)} = \frac{P(R, O, D, G) + P(R, O, D, ¬G)}{P(O, D)} = ??? $$

As you can see, I have managed to answer the first three questions and I imagine these results will be used in the 4th question somehow. The answers are actually online [here](https://chalmersgu-ai-course.github.io/files/AI-exam-2015-06-02-solutions.pdf), but I do not understand the solution.

If someone could show me the steps for answering question 4 and the probability rules used, that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, we have that the Bayesian Network can be factorized as 
$$ P(G,R,O,D) = P(O|R,G)P(D|R)P(G)P(R). \quad (1) $$
Before finding this conditional probability, we must first find the joint, which in this case is given by 
$$ P(R,+o,+d). $$
This is then equivalent to marginalizing the distribution given above, only with known outcomes for $O$ and $D$, which translates to 
$$ \sum_G P(G,R,+o,+d). $$
This is the concept of variable elimination, and factorizing this in terms of equation (1) we obtain
$$ \sum_G P(o+|R,G)P(d+|R)P(G)P(R). $$
Then clearly the sum does not apply to the factors $P(d+|R),P(R)$ so we can bring these out of the sum giving 
$$ P(d+|R)P(R) \sum_G P(o+|R,G)P(G). $$
Again, when marginalizing or summing out a variable, it is useful to think about it as though we are eliminating this variable from our expression, in other words, we ensure the outcomes of this variable no longer impact our final result. You should already have an expression for this sum from part 3 of your question (If you don't it should be relatively straightforward to obtain, think of all the possible outcomes for $R$ and $G$).

Once you've obtained this joint expression, say J(R,+o,+d) you can just apply the definition of conditional probability directly to ascertain 
$$ P(r+|o+,d+) = \frac{P(r+)}{\sum_R J(R,+o,+d)} $$ 
where $P(r+)$ is obtained from the corresponding outcome in the joint.